# passing values from 2 flex movies

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have a flex compiled swf module inside my flex program
I just need to pass it some values like I do it when I use
**chat.swf?username=john** : that works !

I tried it with flex swfLoader and Image

*SWFLoader source="../bin-debug/chat.swf?username=john"*

*Image source="../bin-debug/chat.swf?username=john"*

This does not work: these values are not passed !

what is the simplest way to do it ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Load the swf up and set the variables on it normally like it was a regular object.